# Trying to change display between two divs and then focus on the textarea contained in newly visible div

Tags: jquery, html

I have two `divs` containing `textareas`.  One is set to `display= block;` by default and the other is set to `display: none;`  When I click on a link

`<a href='#' onclick='showFunction()' name='reply'>Reply</a>`

I'm wanting to make the default input `display: none;` and the other `display: block;`.  I also want to focus on the displayed input (which will be at the bottom of the scroll) so the user can just start typing.  My jquery is weak at best, so here is what I have:

```
    var id = '<?php echo $blog_comment_id; ?>';
    function showFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById(id);
      var y = document.getElementById('#top_input');
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }

      y.style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('#focus_here').focus();
    }
```

Right now, the hidden input displays, the one that is showing by default denoted by `id="top_input"` does nothing and it does not focus on the `textarea` denoted `id="focus_here"`.

Here is the respective html for `divs`.  The first is showing by default:

```
<div class='post-comments-list' style="overflow: hidden; display: block;" id="top_input">
    <div class='pw-box add-comment-box' style="margin-top: 2px !important; background: #f7f7f7;">
        <form action="blog_comment_frame.php?post_id=<?php echo $post_id; ?>" id="comment_form" name="postComment<?php echo $post_id; ?>" method="POST">
            <textarea class='post-textarea' name="post_body" required="required" placeholder="Comment here..."></textarea>
            <div class='pw-box-btn'>
                <button class='post-button button' name="postComment<?php echo $post_id ?>" value="ADD">
                    Post
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div><br>
```

The other is not showing:

```
<div class='post-comments-list' id="<?php echo $blog_comment_id; ?>" style="overflow: hidden; display: none;">
    <div class='pw-box add-comment-box' style="margin-top: 2px !important; background: #f7f7f7;">
        <form action="blog_comment_frame.php?post_id=<?php echo $post_id; ?>" id="comment_form" name="postComment<?php echo $post_id; ?>" method="POST">
            <textarea class='post-textarea' id="focus_here" name="post_body" required="required" placeholder="Comment here..."></textarea>
            <div class='pw-box-btn'>
                <button class='post-button button' name="postComment<?php echo $post_id ?>" value="ADD">
                    Post
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've done my best to try and piece together from other posts; it's all I can do as jquery is not at my fingertips, but unfortunately it's still not functioning properly.  Any help / references are appreciated.

> Update

As mentioned in the comments I don't need to pass the `#` sign, so I've removed this.  Now I'm trying to get it to focus on the `textarea` and also scroll to the bottom, as I'm not sure that focusing alone will automatically scroll to the spot.  The `textarea` will always be at the bottom so why not.

Here is new code:

```
var id = '<?php echo $blog_comment_id; ?>';
function showFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  var y = document.getElementById('top_input');
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }

  y.style.display = "none";
  // document.getElementById('focus_here').focus();
 //  $("#reply").click(function(){
    //     $(this).next("#comment_form_see").find("textarea").focus();
    //     return false;
    // });

    window.setTimeout(function(){
           document.getElementById("focus_here").focus();
    },0);

  var iframe = $('#iFrameAutocast').contents();
    iframe.scrollTop(880);
}
```

The result I'm getting is that default `div` disappears and hidden `div` appears as expected.  However, am not focusing on the `textarea` nor am I scrolling to the bottom.  I tried another method for focus that has been commented out.  This didn't work either.

Comment: since getelementbyid is expecting an id, you don't have to pass the pound sign. `document.getElementById('top_input')`

Comment: @imvain2 great, thankyou.  I've removed the pound sign from both `top_input` and `focus_here`.  The top input now disappears, but I'm still not focusing on the new `textarea`.  Do I need to scroll to the bottom somehow?

Answer (score 1):

First, like mentioned in the comments, getElementById expects an ID so you can lose the # sign.

Second, there is a weird solution to focus not working and its using setTimeout. Apparently, the focus command doesn't work as expected across browsers and in all situations.

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
       document.getElementById("focus_here").focus();
},0);
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work.  You can see I did an update to the code block and the results I'm getting.  Still not focusing nor is it scrolling to the bottom of the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post an answer if it helps anyone else out.  I changed above `<a>` tag to this:

```
<a href='#' onclick='showFunction($blog_comment_id)' name='reply'>Reply</a>
```

so were passing data to the function.  Then I modified to this:

```
    function showFunction(id) {
      var x = document.getElementById(id);
      var y = document.getElementById("top_input");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }

      y.style.display = "none";

        window.setTimeout(function(){
               document.getElementById("focus_here" + id).focus();
        },0);
    }
```

Functions as expected.  I'm using this stuff more and more, time to take a class!